# Python Bokeh HoverTool

Tags: python, hover, tooltip, bokeh

Hi I am using the following code for my python hover function

```
 p = Scatter(df_new, x = 'Mobile', y ='Laptop', tooltips = [("brand",'@brand')])
 output_notebook()
 show(p)
```

But I keep getting `???` in brand value while hovering over it can anyone please tell as to what might be the issue here.

Comment: What version are you using? This was an issue that was addressed recently, perhaps you need to update.

Comment: @bigreddot so I updated the package and now I keep getting the error `'dict' object has no attribute 'serialized'`

Comment: @bigreddot I think there was a problem with the upgrade I uninstalled it and then installed it again and everything seems to be working now.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have column **brand** in your DataFrame? Maybe you have capital letter or something?

Comment: That is really strange. Maybe try to use different version of bohek or JS Scripts and bokeh version are different.